# How to filter special characters but keep others

Tags: c#, regex

I trying to filter out special characters but want to keep `tab` and `comma` and some other characters. I need to know how to add comma and tab characters to my regular expression, so that they won't be removed from the string. As soon as I put , I get error.

```
namespace StringSearch {
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

 class TestRegularExpressionValidation {
    static void Main() {
        string[] numbers = {"123_555-0190", "444-234-22450", "690-555-0178", 
                            "146-893-232", "146-555-0122", "4007-555,-0111", 
                            "407-55-0111", "a1b-Cd-EfgH", "a1b-Cd-Efgn",
                            "UM2345678",
                            "11/12/2013 4:10:06 PM              UM2345678                   UM2345678",
                            "407-2-5555"};

        foreach (string s in numbers) {
           string a = RemoveSpecialCharacters(s);
           Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string str) {
        return Regex.Replace(str, "[^a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+", "", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just keep adding to your character class `[]`, but make sure to leave the dash `-` at the beginning or the end of your character class or else you will need to escape `\-`

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9_.,\t-]+
```

See [`Working demo`](http://ideone.com/1S786P)

Answer (score 1):

`-` should be at the end or beginning of a character class i.e `[]`

Your regex would be

```
[^\\w.,\t-]+
```

`\w` is similar to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`